# (Vim key mapping) Is that possible to map '<' or '>' in Vim?

Tags: vim

I want to add such key mapping like:

```
nmap <C->> <C-W>+
nmap <C-<> <C-W>-
```

but it seems doesn't work. 
Is there any problem with the syntax? I'm wondering that the '>' or '<' could be used just like the normal characters.

Comment: what about `nmap + <C-W>+`? it is easier

Comment: Because I would like to use '+' for combination of my key mapping. I did some search and I found the way you gave is a popular use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't possible today, even in GVIM. This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.

Answer (score 5):

It has nothing to do with the syntax, but with one of the following:

1. Terminal may send `<C-<>` as just `<`.
2. If there is a way to get `<C-<>` from a terminal, vim does not know about it.
3. If you are in GUI the representation of `<C-` combos *cannot* possibly handle `<C-<>` because the only keys it knows are from `<C-@>` (ctrl+0x40) to `<C-_>` (ctrl+0x5F) because only these combos can be possibly translated to the ASCII control characters (ones with 0x00—0x1F codes). `<` and `>` both fall out of this range.

And addition: use `nnoremap`, not `nmap`. You don’t need remapping here.

Comment: I'm using PUTTY as my terminal client. How to make sure if my PUTTY send <C-<> as just < or not?

Comment: @Tropicpenguin Type `<C-v><C-<>`. But I do not know how xterm deals with this: it definitely has some extended capabilities which became a standart in many other terminals as well. Note that even if Putty sends something other then `<` then you’ve to map what it sends directly (and thus have terminal-specific mapping) because vim does not support any `<C-` besides those I have already mentioned.